# How to display views in the navigation bar in Xamarin.Forms Shell pages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to display views in the navigation bar in Xamarin.Forms Shell pages?

[menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahqhm.png)

The MainPage starts with like this:

```
MainPage = new AppShell();
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/pages#display-views-in-the-navigation-bar

Comment: oops! thanks!
<Shell.TitleView>
        <Label>title here </Label>
    </Shell.TitleView>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Shell.TitleView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.shell.titleviewproperty?view=xamarin-forms) attached property, of type View, enables any `View` to be displayed in the navigation bar.

While this property can be set on a subclassed [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.shell?view=xamarin-forms) object, it can also be set on any pages that want to display a view in the navigation bar. For example, the following XAML shows displaying a `Label` in the navigation bar:

```
    <Shell.TitleView>
        <Label>title here </Label>
    </Shell.TitleView>
```

Comment: To better elaborate your question and answer, I have edited it.